# JavaMail android: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, email, jakarta-mail, noclassdeffounderror

I am getting this error while trying to send an e-mail using javaMail android:

```
01-23 10:25:23.493: E/AndroidRuntime(20707): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     tk.yteditors.london2013.ConfirmActivity$1
01-23 10:25:23.493: E/AndroidRuntime(20707):    at tk.yteditors.london2013.ConfirmActivity.sendMail(ConfirmActivity.java:124)
01-23 10:25:23.493: E/AndroidRuntime(20707):    at tk.yteditors.london2013.ConfirmActivity.send(ConfirmActivity.java:97)
```

Before that error, this error was also thrown:

```
01-23 10:25:20.753: E/dalvikvm(20707): Could not find class 'tk.yteditors.london2013.ConfirmActivity$1', referenced from method tk.yteditors.london2013.ConfirmActivity.sendMail
```

Can anyone explain what's happening?

Note that i've placed comments on the two lines the error log is placing the errors on. Also note that i've replaced the e-mail server info with invalid data.

and another error log:

```
01-23 10:55:36.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21404): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 10:55:36.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21404): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-23 10:55:36.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21404):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
01-23 10:55:36.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21404):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
01-23 10:55:36.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21404):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
01-23 10:55:36.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21404):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-23 10:55:36.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21404):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-23 10:55:36.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21404):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-23 10:55:36.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21404):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-23 10:55:36.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21404):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 10:55:36.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21404):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-23 10:55:36.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21404):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-23 10:55:36.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21404):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-23 10:55:36.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21404):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-23 10:55:36.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21404): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-23 10:55:36.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21404):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 10:55:36.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21404):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-23 10:55:36.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21404):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
01-23 10:55:36.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21404):    ... 11 more
01-23 10:55:36.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21404): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: tk.yteditors.london2013.ConfirmActivity$1
01-23 10:55:36.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21404):    at tk.yteditors.london2013.ConfirmActivity.sendMail(ConfirmActivity.java:118)
01-23 10:55:36.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21404):    at tk.yteditors.london2013.ConfirmActivity.send(ConfirmActivity.java:90)
01-23 10:55:36.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21404):    ... 14 more
```

Code:

```
package tk.yteditors.london2013;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
import javax.mail.util.ByteArrayDataSource;

import tk.yteditors.london2013.app.App;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;

public class ConfirmActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_confirm);
    setupActionBar();
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.confirmWebView);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    webView.loadUrl(String.valueOf(extras.getString("localAdress")));

    webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    webView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
    webView.getSettings();
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    if(extras.getBoolean("zoomClose", false)){
        webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.CLOSE);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    }
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

    TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.confirmAdress);
    view.setText(extras.getString("webAdress"));
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setupActionBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.MenuSettings:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingActivity.class));
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void delete(View view){
    deleteFile(getIntent().getExtras().getString("fileName"));
    Toast t = Toast.makeText(App.context, "Deleting file...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingActivity.class));
}

public void send(View view){
    try{
        sendMail(); //line 97
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        delete(view);
    }
}

public void sendMail() throws Exception{
    String host = "smtp.server.com";
    String emailAddress = "noEmail@email.com";

    final String from = emailAddress;
    final String pass = "IncorrectPassword";
    String to = emailAddress;

    Multipart multiPart;
    String finalString = "";

    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", emailAddress);
    props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    Session s = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator(){  //line 124
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
            return new PasswordAuthentication(from, pass);
        }
    });
    DataHandler handler=new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(finalString.getBytes(),"text/plain" ));
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(s);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    message.setDataHandler(handler);

    multiPart = new MimeMultipart();

    InternetAddress toAddress = new InternetAddress(to);
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
    message.setSubject("Antwoord van: " +getIntent().getExtras().getString("name"));
    message.setContent(multiPart);
    message.setText("Check bijlage");

    Transport t = s.getTransport("smtp");
    t.connect(host, emailAddress, pass);
    t.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
    t.close();
}

}
```

Thank you very much!

I've also tried using getInstance(props) and getDefaultInstance(props) AND getDefaultInstance(props, null); they don't work.

PS. Don't mind my extremely bad English...

Comment: ah...never mind then, there  was a similar issue in Android studio which required re-sync project. I'm not sure it's relevant to eclipse but give it a try, clean project and recompile it.

Answer (score 0):

`ClassNotFoundException` is thrown when the class cannot be found in the classpath. `NoClassDefFoundError' happens when class cannot be instantiated by`new` because the jvm failed to initialize the class. It could be the constructor threw exceptions, or static block threw up, or version mismatch.

Comment: Once check "Android Private Libraries" on your project (did not touch the library project it references). It works.

Comment: what do you mean, I haven't touched the libs, I have included the javaMail libs in BuildPath..?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the correct definition for `getPasswordAuthentication()` this one:

```
 public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
```

That is, with `public` visibility? That's how I use it anyway.

Does your IDE show any errors on your Anonymous Authenticator class? The `$1` in `tk.yteditors.london2013.ConfirmActivity$1` shows that's the class that can't be initialized.

Comment: Yes, but i also do that, the "from" IS the username and the "pass" IS the password?

Comment: I was referring to the *public* keyword on the method

Comment: Unfortunately: same error... I wonder why it is giving this error, i'll add some printlns to it and see what it does, and what it doesn't execute..

Comment: After I've added this, i saw my project wasn't compiled correctly, corrected it and it throws the same error, but now it also causes an IllegalStateException

Comment: Please add the full stack trace of that exception in your original post.

Comment: The problem is, you cannot use JavaMail directly in Android since it uses components not included in Android's use of Java EE. You can try this implementation: https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/